# Angular 4+: Custom validator AND native min/max arrow selection

Tags: angular, max, min, customvalidator, arrow-keys

I'm trying to add a **dynamic min/max validator** directive that would prevent to type in wrong values **manually** **AND** by using **up/down arrows**, based on my template [min] and [max] values.

It works perfectly when typing in values manually, errors are shown. But I lose the native behavior that prevent to type wrong numbers using the up/down arrows of the input...

html example:

```
<input name="ph" type="number" [(ngModel)]="plotData.soilCharacteristics.ph.value" ngFormMinMax [min]="defaultPlotParameters.soil.ph.min" [max]="defaultPlotParameters.soil.ph.max"/>
```

directive code:

```
@Directive({
selector: '[ngFormMinMax]',
providers: [{ provide: NG_VALIDATORS, useExisting: WfNgMinMaxDirective, multi: true }]
})
export class WfNgMinMaxDirective implements Validator {
    @Input()
    ngModel: NgModel;

    _min: number;
    @Input()
    set min(value: number) {
        this._min = value;
    }

    _max: number;
    @Input()
    set max(value: number) {
        this._max = value;
    }

    validate(control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null {
        if (control.value > this._max) {
            return { max: { invalid: true } };
        }

        if (control.value < this._min) {
            return { min: { invalid: true } };
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Behaviour:

with [max] value set to 10, I can manually type in 11 and the error will show, **but i can also go to 11 by using the up/down arrows** of the input. When removing the directive the up/down key are blocked to 10 like expected, but I lose the manual validation...

It seems that the default behaviour for up/down key is overriden, is there a way to prevent this ? I thought using the NG_VALIDATORSproviders was the way of doing it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have achieved the validation using Reactive Form with Form Control and Custom Validator. We need to store the last success value and we need to update it in the UI.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-homnk5?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

In Template, you can display error msg using name.errors?.invalid

Answer (score 0):

This is based on something I've got in production code, but you'll have to modify it:

```
@HostListener('keydown', ['$event'])
public keydown(event: any): void {
  // Check for the value of the key pressed; if it is
  // the up or down keys then trigger the validation manually.
  this.form.updateValueAndValidity();
}
```

That might help you on the way to finding the solution particular to your code.

Comment: Just tried it and it didn't work !


This is really wierd as I have already added custom min/max validators to an input before and I kept the 'blocked arrow' behavior...


It looks like passing by the directive method for this overrides the native behavior, but editing customValidators in the template's controller directly keeps the behavior...


I can't really afford to edit manually each input and set their min/max via customValidators, I have way  too much of them through my app...

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
[attr.min]="defaultPlotParameters.soil.ph.min"
```

Comment: Lack of explanation on what it does. Try to avoid posting answers with just a code. Thank you